# inline ajax and document.ready doubt

Tags: jquery, html

I am making an ajax call inline as below and storing the response in global variable and accessing later for some performance reasons.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var gblAjaxResponse;
   $.ajax({
      url: '/test.aspx',
      success: function(data) {
       gblAjaxResponse=data;
      }      
    });                                     
</script>
```

Now i want to use this global variable in document.ready of an ajax file. Once the DOM is ready , i have to use this data on some divs on that page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 alert(gblAjaxResponse);   

});
```

I have the following questions now.

1) As ajax is asyncrnous call is it sure that i always get the response into that global variable by the time i ready document.ready.
2) Are there any chances that my document.ready code gets executed below the ajax success handler returns
3) I don't want to use asyn false option as it can hang.
4) Is there anyway to check if success is completed and returned data.

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You definitely can't be sure that gblAjaxResponse will get set by the time the DOM is ready. That's just the nature of AJAX.

Comment: @kennis any ideas or solutions???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) As ajax is asyncrnous call is it
>   sure that i always get the response
>   into that global variable by the time
>   i ready document.ready.

No, `document.ready` can be executed before.

> 2) Are there any chances that my
>   document.ready code gets executed
>   below the ajax success handler returns

Yes

> 4) Is there anyway to check if success
>   is completed and returned data.

Basing on kennis' answer, you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var gblAjaxResponse;
   $.ajax({
       url: '/test.aspx',
       success: function(data) {
          gblAjaxResponse = data;
          myCallbackFunction();
      }
   });

   function myCallbackFunction(){
       alert(gblAjaxResponse);
   }                              
</script>
```

If you need to use `gblAjaxResponse` in `document.ready`, you could do this too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var gblAjaxResponse = null;
   $.ajax({
       url: '/test.aspx',
       success: function(data) {
          gblAjaxResponse = data;
      }
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){
       //Wait until gblAjaxResponse has value:
       var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
           if(gblAjaxResponse !== null){
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               myCallbackFunction();
           }
       }, 100);
   });
   function myCallbackFunction(){           
       alert(gblAjaxResponse);
   }                              
</script>
```

Comment: your setInterval logic is perfect , this is what i am looking for

Comment: Thanks :). I changed it to setTimeout so myCallbackFunction executes only once.

Comment: #edgar , that direction is enough , i got it know , thanks very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my recommendation:

Just put that AJAX call inside $(document).ready(), then execute a callback function on success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var gblAjaxResponse;
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: '/test.aspx',
          success: function(data) {
              gblAjaxResponse = data;
              myCallbackFunction();
          }
       });  
   });

   myCallbackFunction(){
       alert(gblAjaxResponse);
   }                              
</script>
```

Comment: i don't want to make the ajax call on document.ready , that is the whole reason , otherwise its pretty easy.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your particular use-case. Why the aversion to waiting for the doc.ready?

Comment: for performance reasons i want to make the ajax call at the the top of page in the order controls loads , if you make the ajax call in the document.ready ,it will wait until the complete dom is loaded and then makes the call..

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But DOM loads prettttty quick. Remember, document.ready doesn't wait for images/media to load - just for the DOM. It's pretty much instant.

Answer (score 0):

While the function callback is the best method to avoid hanging the script (and possibly the page), you can also force the call to be synchronous:

```
$.ajax{
  url: blah,
  type: json,
  async: false
}
```

Like I said, this forces the rest of your javascript to wait on the request, however.

Comment: @ b , e , thanks for the answer but i don't want async :false...at all

Comment: @hollenbeck, kobe specified in his question that he doesn't want to use `async`.